# How can I terminate execution in jenkins pipeline when we use nested try-catch blocks?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, try-catch

I'm using a nested try-catch block to define a jenkins pipeline. At the execution time, if I have another try-catch block in the parent try-catch block and something goes wrong in the child try-catch block, it will jump to the child catch block then again will continue executing the code in the parent try-catch block.

I have tried setting the **currentBuild.result='Failure'** and **error "Error occurred"** but still, it will proceed with the execution. I want the pipeline status to be a failure and terminate the execution of the rest of the code.

```
try{
    stage('stage1'){
        //do something
    }

    try{
        stage('stage2'){
            //do something
        }

    }catch(Exception err1){
        error "Error Occurred"
        currentBuild.result='Failure'
    }



}catch(Exception ex){
    // Do something if stage 1 fails 
}
```

If the stage 2 fails, it shouldn't jump to the stage 1's catch statement. Can someone please suggest me a good way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/887) should also answer your question.

A single return after setting `currentBuild.result = 'Failure'` should work for you. Take care, that the return is outside of a stage, or else it will just exit the stage.