# Scripted Pipeline - terminate execution in jenkins pipeline when we use nested try-catch blocks?

Tags: jenkins, try-catch, jenkins-groovy

I'm using a nested try-catch block to define a jenkins pipeline. At the execution time, if I have another try-catch block in the parent try-catch block and something goes wrong in the child try-catch block, it will jump to the child catch block then again will continue executing the code in the parent try-catch block.

I have tried setting the currentBuild.result='Failure' or currentBuild.result='Aborted' and error ("exiting stage" ) or return  but still, it will proceed with the execution. I want the pipeline status to be a failure and terminate the execution of the rest of the code.

I see someone posted 3yrs back before [How can I terminate execution in jenkins pipeline when we use nested try-catch blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001556/how-can-i-terminate-execution-in-jenkins-pipeline-when-we-use-nested-try-catch-b) but not able to get it

```
try{

  stage('stage1'){
     //do something
  }
     try{
        stage('stage2'){
        //do something
      }
    }catch(Exception err1){
      error "Exit stage"
      currentBuild.result='Failure'
    }

}catch(Exception ex){
   // Do something if stage 1 fails 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to use nested `try {} catch() {}` blocks. Instead, there are a couple options for you:

- The simplest solution would be to try solving this into a single stage. If both stages belong to the same logic, there's nothing wrong with it:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("stage1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        // do something
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        // do something if block above failed
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Jenkins doesn't keep track of stage status for the purpose of conditional execution of the next stages. One way to accomplish that is writing a status file in one stage and reading it in the next one. Something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("stage1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        sh 'cat /tmp'
                        writeFile encoding: 'utf-8', file: 'stageStatus', text: 'SUCCESS'
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        writeFile encoding: 'utf-8', file: 'stageStatus', text: 'FAILED'
                        print("Ooopsie!")
                        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            sh 'exit 1'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage("stage2") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def previousStageStatus = readFile encoding: 'utf-8', file: 'stageStatus'
                    if (previousStageStatus == 'FAILED') {
                        print('The previous stage failed')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the "stage2" will be shown as "SUCCESS" everytime in your pipeline, because no matter what, it will be ran, even if it does absolutely nothing. But still, you should know when it will be triggered, because "stage1" will be shown as "FAILED" in your pipeline.

At this point, somebody should rise and say "Hey, what about `when {}` statements?". Unfortunately, they're analysed at the beginning of the job, and not during it.

Best regards!